# Function not retrieving one of the parameters

Tags: matlab, function, octave

This might just be a really small mistake but I'm getting an error when calling a function:

```
error: 'D' undefined near line 7 column 25
```

My function is:

```
function dxdt = s(t,u,D,D0,ni,ax,ay,bn,bx,ex,ey,epsilon)
  D = D0*(1+epsilon*sin(2*pi*t));
  n = u(1);
  x = u(2);
  y = u(3); 
  dxdt = [D*ni - D*n - (ax*(n/(bn+n))*x); ...
          -D*x+ex*ax*(n/(bn+n))*x-ay*(x/(bx+x))*y; ...
          -D*y+ey*ay*(x/(bx+x))*y];
end
```

I'm putting everything here but I think only the `D = ...` part matters. And in my script I'm calling the function in this way:

```
[T,U] = ode45(@(t,u) s(t,u,D,D0,ni,ax,ay,bn,bx,ex,ey,epsilon),interval,u0);
```

Comment: Where is `D` defined in your calling script?

Comment: I'm defining it in the function only. Should I input the `D=D0*(1+epsilon*sin(2*pi*t)` in the script as well?

Comment: If it's defined in the function only, it shouldn't be one of the parameters passed to the function.

Comment: When you create your anonymous function in the call to `ode45`, you have to have all the other variables except for `t` and `u` defined already.

Comment: In your function `D` is an input, but then you evaluate it as `D=D0*(1+epsilon*sin(2*pi*t));`

Comment: Ah very well. I thought that adding it to both script and function would create an overlap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your call to [`ode45`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) you are creating this [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
@(t,u) s(t,u,D,D0,ni,ax,ay,bn,bx,ex,ey,epsilon)
```

This function will accept two arguments `t` and `u` that should be passed to it when invoked. All of the other variables, such a `D`, need to be defined before creating the anonymous function. Your error indicates that they are not.

These additional arguments to `s` will also [be fixed at the value they had when the anonymous function was created](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621), so even if you change `D` after creating the anonymous function, the function will still use the previous value of `D` when calling function `s`.

It may also be helpful to check out some documentation regarding variable scope:

- [Base and Function Workspaces](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html)
- [Share Data Between Workspaces](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html)